# Caching of provision profiles issue in iOS

Tags: ios, caching, profile, ios-provisioning, provisioning-profile

I am using *In-House* subscription of Apple. I built app and distributed it via web link. Everything was okay, so I could install this app by calling manifest from iPhone's safari browser. Then I revoked certificate and remove provision profile - that causes my app to fail to run (then I found that this happens all the time when you revoke certificate.)

To make my app working again I created new certificate and *in-house provision profile* - then I resigned my current .ipa file and replaced it on web server.

Then I tried to install app on different devices

1. I installed it on 1 iPad and it works, I see in settings new provision profile appeared.
2. I tried to install same app on 2nd iPad and it fails during installation process. And what is strange it installed old provision profile to my settings (I think this is some kind of caching or whatever). I deleted all apps, all profiles and reboot - but no luck - I can't still install this app to this particular iPad.

May be someone had same issue, please assist me how should I clean cache if it's related to caching issue.

P.S. I want to fix it without wiping the device

Answer (score 0):

Is your second iPad connected via USB to your development computer while you're doing this testing?  If it is, Xcode's Organizer will often just restore the provisioning profile that you're trying to delete.  If this is the case, try deleting it from the Organizer as well.

Comment: No it's not connected niter to PC nor Mac (to prevent sync with them), especially server does not have old .ipa file. It seems it is cached somewhere on the way between server and device